# Customizing self.editButtonItem with Check and UnCheck- HELP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, rightbarbuttonitem

So with regards to the rightBarButtonItem . I have

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

When I press Edit, I get animation and a vertical stripe on the left side of each TableViewCell. 
When I click that stripe, the Delete button appears on the right side of THAT tableViewCell.

I want to do two things.

1. Rename that 'Delete' to 'Check'
2. If it is checked, it should display 'Uncheck' to be tapped.

I would appreciate any help on that..

:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [`tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in your table view delegate.

Comment: That was a Wicked Answer ! Thanks. Could you also let me in with the logic for setting up the UnCheck button if it is checked ?

Comment: Dan, I got it. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the answer I did this.

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

 UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
 {
     selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 }
 else 
     if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
     {
         selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     }

}
```

and

```
- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{

    return (@"Check");
}
else 
    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {

        return (@"UnCheck");
    }

}
```