# uitableview edit mode

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want when click on edit mode , the action when select a cell be differ , I mean

in normal case when select a cell it be checked (accessory of checking appear)
in edit case an accessory of type button appear when click I navigate to another screen

any suggestion to do that

I have only selectedrowatindex , and commitedit

how to implement that please

like in the image if I clicked edit , the button appear and if I clicked the row (pacs for example I can edit it ) or select the normal delete button 
I mean how selectedrowatindex I know either I am in edit mode or not , and how to add accessory to the cell that in edit mode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at my solution in

[Customizing self.editButtonItem with Check and UnCheck- HELP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219289/customizing-self-editbuttonitem-with-check-and-uncheck-help)