# Change the Width of UISearchBars on a TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, tableview

I am required to create two UISearchBars in my tableView. I want both of them of equal width on top of the table (side-by-side).

I have created two outlets of UISearchBar, and property and de alloc for them. I am finding it hard to place (I mean fit) both of them in the view. I get only one search bar expanding to the FULL width of the screen. How do I fit two ?

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 4, 45)];
zipSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 0, 4, 45)];

searchBar.placeholder = @"School Name";
zipSearchBar.placeholder=@"Zip";

searchBar.delegate = self;
zipSearchBar.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView= zipSearchBar;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView= searchBar;
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply reassigning it when you do `self.tableView.tableHeaderView= searchBar;`. You will have to build a view that contains both the search bars and then set it to the table's header view. Something like this,

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 45)];
zipSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 120, 45)];

searchBar.placeholder = @"School Name";
zipSearchBar.placeholder=@"Zip";

searchBar.delegate = self;
zipSearchBar.delegate = self;

UIView * comboView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
[comboView addSubview:searchBar];
[comboView addSubview:zipSearchBar];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView= comboView;
[comboView release];
```

Comment: FML ! I got carried away with all the articles online which said I cannot change the width of the UISearchBar. MANY THANKS @DEEPAK.

Comment: @Deepak : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258001/real-time-search-in-uitableview

Comment: Saw it. I don't think there is.

Comment: @Deepak. I thought I should just follow up... Anyways... NSRange helps with RealTime Search !

Comment: @ Deepak: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281451/presentmodalviewcontroller-problem