# Real Time Search in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, search

I have implemented a *UISearchBar* for finding an element in *UITableView*. Everything seems to work fine, and now I am at the part where I need to actually perform real-time search for every key pressed in the *textField*, and narrow down the search with every button press.

So before I start coding, I wanted to know if there is any inbuilt library function that could help me with live search ? (string comparison) or anything ?

Your answer could save me some time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It so happens that there is in fact an inbuilt function that helps with RealTime Search. Phew !

```
NSRange match = [userNameString rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
// match.location will provide the exact location of a match of searchText with a String
// match.length will provide the length of match
```