# presentModalViewController Problem !

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, presentmodalviewcontroller

So,

I have a form (which is basically a UITableView), and once I finish the form, I click the 'Done' button which is on top of the screen.

After clicking, I need to add the data to another tableView (which is in another tableViewController). This table is also inside a Navigation Controller.

After I press the Done Button, I need the presentModalViewController to be the new TableView (with the new data) along with the Navigation Controller on top of the tableView.

**So, to summarize:**

- The Done Button is in someTableViewController.
- I need to add an object (lets just say I am adding a a name called "Dobby" for simplicity) into another tableView called dogTableViewController.
- I reload the data , and present the screen which has dogTableViewController inside the dogNavigationController.
- All the classes are referenced properly and included.

I am pasting the -(IBAction) when the Done Button is clicked.

```
-(IBAction) doneWithData: (UIBarButtonItem*) sender{


 UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[indicator sizeToFit];
indicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

indicator.tag = 1;
[self.view addSubview:indicator];
[indicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
indicator.center = self.view.center;
indicator.hidden = FALSE;
[indicator startAnimating];

if (self.dogTableViewController == nil)
{
    DogTableViewController *temp = [[DogTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.dogTableViewController = temp;
    [temp release];
}

if (self.dogNavigationController == nil)
{
    DogNavigationController *temp = [[DogNavigationController alloc] init];
    self.dogNavigationController = temp;
    [temp release];
}

[self.dogTableViewController.dogArray addObject:@"Dobby"];
[self.dogTableViewController.tableView reloadData];

NSLog (@"%@", [self.dogTableViewController.dogArray objectAtIndex:0]); 
//Prints out "Null" //

[self presentModalViewController:dogNavigationController animated:YES];


[indicator release];

}
```

**When I do all this and Click the Done button,**

I get an empty Navigation Screen with NO TABLE in it. Plus I also had some buttons on the dogNavigationController screen. Nothings visible !!

My objective is to just transfer the screen to this new screen (which happens to be a home screen, and not the rootController). Do you think I should go with the modalViewController for this task ? Do you think I should use some other way to transfer data to another screen ?

p.s. I do not want to use PushViewController.

Comment: Home screen? Shouldn't you be popping then?

Comment: This is how the app works... 1 -> 2 -> 3-> 4-> 1

Comment: I click the done button in 4, and I need 1 to display with added data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

rather. To get the root view controller, you can do,

```
DogTableViewController * viewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[viewController.dogArray addObject:aDog];
```

**Original Answer**

Shouldn't you be initializing a navigation controller with the root view controller?

```
DogNavigationController *temp = [[DogNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.dogTableViewController];
```

Comment: The rootController is a TabBarController

Comment: So I changed the code as you had posted above. I can see the dogNavigationController's correct title now. I do not see the any UIBarButtonItem, and I do not see the tableView .

Comment: popToRootViewController did the trick, and I am now in the dogNavigationController. Thanks man.  BUT ; an object is not getting added to it !!..... and the table is null.

Comment: DogTableViewController *viewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [viewController.dogArray addObject:@"Dobby"];
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];
    
    [self.dogTableViewController.dogArray addObject:@"Dobby"];
    [self.dogTableViewController.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog (@"%@", [self.dogTableViewController.dogArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog (@"%@", [viewController.dogArray objectAtIndex:0]);

Comment: put the `[self.tableView reloadData];` statement in the `viewWillAppear` method of `DogTableViewController`. How are you setting the `self.dogTableViewController` property? As such, have you initialized the array? It could be `nil` without initialization which will give you `null` output.

Comment: Wow. I did not initialize it at all. I now went to init - method and initialized it.  Now my NSLogs changed to Dobby and NULL

Comment: Still I do not see the object Dobby added to the tableView

Comment: `self.dogTableViewController` must be `nil` too. Did you add `[self.tableView reloadData];` to the `viewWillAppear` method? You should also try logging the `dogArray` there.

Comment: Wow. It displays NULL in viewWillAppear

Comment: You should initialize the `dogArray` property in the `viewDidLoad` of `DogTableViewController`.

Comment: so, I initialized the dogarray property in the ViewDidLoad as well... Now App crashes when I press the DOne button, and the error is with the NSLogs. (if I comment out NSLogs, No error ; But no object is added either). I am pasting the error below. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: How are you initializing the array?

Comment: Like this. NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.dogArray = array;
    [array release];

Comment: Hey Deepak.. Any chances of you coming on chat ?

Comment: Sure. I have joined the iPhone/iPad one

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"UserDidAddDogNotification" object:self userInfo:info];

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNotificationCenter postNotification:object:userInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6811200'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I can't say without additional data. [`Here`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/DogDayAfternoon.zip) is a sample project that does the same thing that we discussed yesterday. Hopefully it will help you figure out what the error was.

Comment: Things work. Got the error fixed, and things are working... These were the changes. //NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    //NSString * dogName = [info stringForKey:@"dogName"];
    NSString * dogName = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"dogName"];......... and the other error was postNotification instead of postNotificationName.

Comment: @Deepak: Can I add a lot of observers in many view controllers so that they also get the userInfo ? And should I implement the DidAddDog for all those classes ?

Comment: Yes you can. The method name can be anything but you will have to implement it for all those classes. One thing which I might not have done in the sample is that you should remove yourself as an observer in the `dealloc` method or otherwise it would result in error when a deallocated object is messaged by the notification center.

Comment: in dealloc ... [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; ?