# Disable blinking cursor in UITextField?

Tags: uitextfield, uidatepicker, text-cursor

I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208118/uidatepicker-in-uitextfield-in-uitableview-realtime-update) and succesfully set up a UITextField that gets updated with a UIDatePicker. However the cursor in the UITextField is blinking, which seems quite a bit awkward to me.

Is there any solution to get rid of that cursor?

Answer (score 48):

I realise this is an old question, but with the updates to iOS 7, it is now possible to hide the cursor by doing the following:

`[[self textFieldName] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

It will only work on iOS 7+ however.

Answer (score 39):

Subclass UITextfield and Override the **`- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position`** method and return **`CGRectZero`**.

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position {
    return CGRectZero;
}
```

Comment: It's not working with iOS 4.3. UITextInput Protocol adapted only iOS 5 and above.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.  It's to the point and addresses the specific part we want to hide -- namely the caret.  This is the best solution out of all of them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

I hope it will helpful to you.

Set Cursor UIColor -> Empty.

```
 [[self.textField valueForKey:@"textInputTraits"] setValue:[UIColor clearColor] forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];
```

In Swift : 2.3

```
self.textField.valueForKey("textInputTraits")?.setValue(UIColor.clearColor() , forKey:"insertionPointColor")
```

Comment: any one know the swift version?

Comment: A proper answer should not be using private API values.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get jcm's solution to work. What I ended up doing was to subclass UILabel to mimic a UITextField's interactive functionality without the parts that I didn't want (like the cursor). I wrote a blog post about it here:

http://pietrorea.com/2012/07/how-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-uitextfield/

Basically, the UILabel subclass needs to overwrite isUserInteractionEnabled, inputView, inputViewAccessory and canBecomeFirstResponder. It's only a few lines of code and it makes more sense.

Comment: i recently added your PRLabel class in my project.. but i dont know what i did wrong, it is seriously messing upp with the tableview index ... i think when the picker view is shown, the tableview is scrolled but visually not updated ... i have a PRLabel in section 1 .. i touch it , picker view shows then when i touch a cell in section 0 it is interpreting as section 1 ..

Answer (score 2):

Totally silly hack, but if you set the text field's tint color in the `UIView` section of the Interface Builder property inspector to match the background color, the cursor will appear invisible:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to overlay another UITextField on top of the one whose cursor I wanted to hide.  Then in the delegate method textFieldShouldBeginEditing I set the other textField to become first responder and returned NO.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.tag==TAG_OF_DUMMY_TEXTFIELD) {
        [otherField becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And then in the method the date picker calls:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@YOUR_DATE_FORMAT];
dummyField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

In Interface Builder otherField (the one with the datePicker input view) is behind dummyField (the one that hides the cursor).

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but you could also set the Opacity of the tint color to 0%.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to be the easiest to implement.

Make sure you define UITextFieldDelegate in your .h file:

```
.... UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

In your .m file, add this to the method you call fo the date picker:

```
[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

This will prevent the textfield from blinking.

Answer (score 0):

Balaji's approach does work.

I also used such KVC solutions many times.
Despite it seems to be undocumented, but it works. Frankly, you don't use any
private methods here - only Key-Value Coding which is legal.

It is drastically different from [addNewCategoryTextField textInputTraits].

P.S. Yesterday my new app appeared at AppStore without any problems with this approach. And it is not the first case when I use KVC in changing some read-only properties (like navigatonBar) or private ivars.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `BOOL cursorless` property to `UITextField` in a category via associated objects.

```
@interface UITextField (Cursorless)

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL cursorless;

@end
```

Then use method swizzling to swizzle `caretRectForPosition:` with a method that toggles between `CGRectZero` and its default value using `cursorless`.

This leads to a simple interface via a drop-in category. This is demonstrated in the following files.

Simply drop them in and get the benefit of this simple interface

`UITextField` category:
https://github.com/rexmas/RexDK/blob/master/RexDK/UI/UITextField%2BRXCursorless.h
https://github.com/rexmas/RexDK/blob/master/RexDK/UI/UITextField%2BRXCursorless.m

Method Swizzling:
https://github.com/rexmas/RexDK/blob/master/RexDK/Foundation/NSObject%2BRXRuntimeAdditions.h
https://github.com/rexmas/RexDK/blob/master/RexDK/Foundation/NSObject%2BRXRuntimeAdditions.m