# Can I make UITextField invisible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I checked out [iPhone: How can I make a UITextField invisible but still clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749028/iphone-how-can-i-make-a-uitextfield-invisible-but-still-clickable), but the OP has something else going on and the answers didn't seem to help me out of my fix.

I have a UITextField in which the user has to enter text.  Instead of the standard UITextField graphic, I want to use a lovely graphic that's been designed for that purpose.  The user would still need to be able to enter text and see the text s/he's entering, but I need the textfield to be invisible so that the graphic can show from underneath it.

How can I do this?  Or is there another way to do what I'm after?

Comment: How about setting background color to clear color? `[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` Also set the border style as `UITextBorderStyleNone`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer. You can try this,

```
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

And then set the border style as `UITextBorderStyleNone`.

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
yourTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

should do it

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be hiding the `UITextView` itself and just adding a transparent button that will call the keyboard to display.

Otherwise, the other answers should work.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option is to do it in interface builder. Choose the first uitext field style with no border  and that's it.